# React: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'recipe_name')

Tags: reactjs

Just wondering what is going wrong here (I am new to react). My fetch request works and brings in data from backend when the user makes a query in `input`. But now I receive this error.

```
RecipeDBTest.jsx:54 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'recipe_name')
    at GetRecipe (RecipeDBTest.jsx:54:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16175:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20913:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22416:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4161:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4210:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4274:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27405:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26513:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26422:1)
```

This is the relevant React component's code:

```
import './RecipeForm.css'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import PageContainer from '../components/ui/PageContainer.js'

export default function GetRecipe() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [recipeInfo, setRecipeInfo] = useState('')

  const retrieveRecipe = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(name)
    fetch(`http://localhost:3001/getjoinedrecipes/?name=${name}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
    })
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json)
        let result = json.map((row, idx) => {
          return <span key={idx}>{row}</span>
        })
        setRecipeInfo(result)
      })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="recipe-form-container">
        <form className="recipe-form">
          <div className="page-header">
            <h1>Get Recipe!</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="recipe-title recipe-element">
            <label>Recipe Name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={name}
              onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}></input>
          </div>

          <div className="get-button-container">
            <button className="get-recipe" onClick={(e) => retrieveRecipe(e)}>
              Get Recipe
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <PageContainer
        RecipeName={recipeInfo[0].recipe_name}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Is this something to do with state? I don't fully understand how it is going wrong, as it works when I remove the `<PageContainer>` and `RecipeName` prop. Here is the returned data from the fetch call:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
id: 11
ingredient_id: 11
ingredient_name: "lemon"
measure: "cups"
quantity: "2"
recipe_blurb: "Delicious"
recipe_id: 6
recipe_name: "Bolognese"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing `recipeInfo` as a string, updating it as an array of react objects and accessing them (when passing props to PageContainer) as API data response object.
You can't access `recipe_name` as
`recipeInfo[0].recipe_name`.

Update your state initialization as:

```
  const [recipeInfo, setRecipeInfo] = useState([])
```

Then check for data before accessing it, as:

```
    <PageContainer
        recipeName={recipeInfo.length ? recipeInfo[0].recipe_name:""}
      />
```

Also you should store the array returned from API in `recipeInfo` state instead of storing elements. Move the mapping of data to return of `PageContainer` (This isn't needed if you are using only the first element of the array) .

**What Should Go in State?**

*State should contain data that a component's event handlers may change to trigger a UI update. In real apps this data tends to be very small and JSON-serializable. When building a stateful component, think about the minimal possible representation of its state, and only store those properties in state.*

[Refer this for more details.](http://web.archive.org/web/20150419023006/http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#what-should-go-in-state)

So update the `retrieveRecipe` function as

```
const retrieveRecipe = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(name)
    fetch(`http://localhost:3001/getjoinedrecipes/?name=${name}`, 
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
    })
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setRecipeInfo(json)
      })
  }
```

Comment: Okay thanks for the advice but nothing is being add into the dom?

Comment: @deadant88 Check the updated answer. Also check the casing of `recipeName` when passing to `PageContainer `. It's a better practice to write prop name in lower camel case.